# ROSARIA vs p2os for Pioneer LX

Tags: ros, pioneer, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am curious as to which of the two (ROSARIA or P2OS) would be more adequate for a pioneer LX mobile robot.
I am asking because although I would prefer to use p2os it does seem like an older package while the LX model is rather new.

As a side note, does anyone know if there is any package for auto-docking into charging station?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240043/rosaria-vs-p2os-for-pioneer-lx/) by [AbelC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27560/abelc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use ROSARIA with the LX.  The LX has a few differences from other Pioneer robots that would need to be implemented in the P2OS node; if anyone wants to discuss those let me know.  (Mostly in how the robot computer, controller, and some components are interconnected, the basic protocol is the same.)

The full auto-docking process is implemented in the ARNL library (navigating to the docking station, then switching to a mode where it drives into the dock and remains at the dock until some condition (e.g. fully charged) or told to switch out of that mode.)  There is a ROS wrapper for ARNL you can run instead of the ROSARIA node if you want (ros-arnl, http://wiki.ros.org/ros-arnl).

Some of the tools used by ARNL to implement docking are available in ARIA however such as sensing the charging station, turning and moving into the station, etc.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbelC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27560/abelc/) on 2016-07-25**:
Thanks for the quick response. I'm going to give the ARNL wrapper a chance as it does seem to provide what I'm looking for.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2016-07-30**:
OK. There is still some work being done on ros-arnl to add features and find bugs, see the discussions on the issues section of the ros-arnl github repository.